# Expanding frames to fill space when window size changes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

Here is the complete relevant code that I am working with:

```
    JPanel songDetails = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout() ); 

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();   
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
        constraints.weightx = 1.0; 
        constraints.gridx = 0; 
        constraints.gridy = 0;  

    for(int i = 0; i < songOptions.length; i++, constraints.gridx++){ 
        songDetails.add(this.buttons[i],constraints);
    }

    constraints.gridy = 1; 

    for(int i = 0; i < songInfo.length; i++, constraints.gridy++){ 

        constraints.gridwidth = 1; 
        constraints.gridx = 0; 
        songDetails.add(this.labels[i],constraints); 

        constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; 
        constraints.gridx = 1; 
        songDetails.add(this.fields[i],constraints); 
    }


    JList<Song> list = new JList<Song>(this.lib); //data has type Object[] 
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);


    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane();
        listScroller.setViewportView(list);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
    constraints.weightx = 1.0; 
    constraints.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE; 
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; 
    constraints.gridx = 0; 
    constraints.gridy = 0;   
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(listScroller,constraints); 
        constraints.gridy++; 
        add(songDetails, constraints);
```

In main I initialize the frame as follows:

```
    SongLib myLibrary = new SongLib("Song Library", pathName );
        myLibrary.setVisible(true);
        myLibrary.setSize(300, 250);// Sets the Frame Size
        myLibrary.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,250));
        myLibrary.setResizable(true);//Makes the size not fixed
        myLibrary.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Make the Frame appear centered
        myLibrary.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Tells program to exit when the 'x'(close) button is pressed
```

My problem is that when I expand the frame, it expands just fine horizontally(width), but doesn't expand at all vertically. I thought that changing the fill value would do that for me, but it isn't. 
Also if possible to change the font size when this change happens.

If it wouldn't be too complicated I would also like to give the user the ability to change the relative sizes of each frame. I'm thinking some sort of action listener will be needed. If it is I will look into that later, but if there is something I'm overlooking it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Notice in your code:

```
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();   
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
    constraints.weightx = 1.0;   // *********
    constraints.gridx = 0; 
    constraints.gridy = 0;
```

You're not setting weighty for your GridBagConstraints, just the weightx. Set this and it will expand vertically.

e.g.,

```
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();   
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
    constraints.weightx = 1.0; 
    constraints.weighty = 1.0;  // ***** added *****
    constraints.gridx = 0; 
    constraints.gridy = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the expansion problem solved i can still tell you that changing the font would require a listener like this:

```
myLibrary.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() 
    {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {
            //Call method that changes the font of each object
        }
    });
```

I'am not quite sure what you mean with changing the relative sizes of each **frame(?)** but if you mean each component inside your frame i would suggest doing a bit more research first and then (if necessary) post a new question.